# UITableView will not refresh once list is deleted. self.tableView.reloadData() does not work either

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm relatively new to developing Swift and iOS, but not new to code. I'm a little annoyed with the table view.

I have tried countless times to use `self.tableView.reloadData()` but to no avail. I have also tried

```
async call dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But this doesn't want to work either. I'll post function so that maybe someone can enlighten me where I goofed up. I really do appreciate the help.

```
@IBAction func clearList(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Clear List?",
    message: "Are you sure you want to clear the list?",
    preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let yesClearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    self.clearListNow("GroceryList")

    })

    let noClearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        //do nothing aka don't clear list
    })
    alert.addAction(yesClearAction)
    alert.addAction(noClearAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

And just in case anyone wanted to see what `clearListNow` does...

```
func clearListNow(entity: String) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "GroceryList")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do
    {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        for managedObject in results
        {
            let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
            managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Detele all data in \(entity) error : \(error) \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

I have also tried to use `self.tableView.reloadData()` in the `clearListNow` function. I have tried to place the statement in both at the same time, and separately and neither scenario worked.

Comment: did you try to put your code inside of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { ... })` block to avoid async loading?

Comment: Do you have set the delegate and data source of the tableview? And implemented both? Please show this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to reload data in yesClearAction
you should have something like :

```
 @IBAction func clearList(sender: AnyObject) {
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Clear List?",
  message: "Are you sure you want to clear the list?",
  preferredStyle: .Alert)

  let yesClearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
  self.clearListNow("GroceryList")
  self.tableView.reloadData()
})

let noClearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
  //do nothing aka don't clear list
 })
alert.addAction(yesClearAction)
alert.addAction(noClearAction)
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Let me know if this works ! :)

**UPDATE**

I have done this code and it works fine for me

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var rows: NSMutableArray!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.rows = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func clearList(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Clear List?",
        message: "Are you sure you want to clear the list?",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let yesClearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.clearListNow("GroceryList")
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

    let noClearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        //do nothing aka don't clear list
    })
    alert.addAction(yesClearAction)
    alert.addAction(noClearAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func clearListNow(entity: String) {
    self.rows.removeAllObjects()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return self.rows.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FruitCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MyCell
    cell!.textLabel?.text = self.rows[indexPath.row] as? String
    return cell!
}

}
```

here a screen shot of my storyboard :

[image]

Comment: I have tried to put the self.tableView.reloadData() after calling the clearlistnow function and it still doesn't refresh the table :/

Comment: check if the delegate of your tableView is correctly linked.
you should have something like self.tableView.delegate = self; AND self.tableView.dataSource = self.
Also you can do this in on your storyboard

Comment: Or may be your clearListNow method does not really delete records from database !! 
Make some breakpoints in this method and check the result of deleting request then check in database file if the records are correctly deleted...

Answer (score 1):

Reload your `tableView` when use press Yes in your alert as shown into below code:

```
let yesClearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

      self.clearListNow("GroceryList")
      self.tableView.reloadData() 

})
```

Comment: I have tried to do this and it still doesn't refresh the table...` let         yesClearAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: {                (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        self.clearListNow("GroceryList")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      
         })`

Comment: Can you share demo project?

Answer (score 0):

As per your current code TableView Reload after AlertView present 
so, tableView DataSource (Array) not change and tableview Display datasource(array) data.

try to relod table after

```
self.clearListNow("GroceryList")
```

i.e.

```
self.clearListNow("GroceryList")
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

or

into  func clearListNow(entity: String)

after for loop 
 i.e.

```
for managedObject in results
{
let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

so tableview get latest datasource and display it.

Let me know if this works...

Comment: I have tired to insert after the for loop and still within the do statement and outside of the do statement and it creates more of an issue with my app. The list doesn't update after an item is added anymore... so it reacts the same way as when i'm trying to clear the list... just does nothing until reload... thanks for your help.